# How to sort lists of dictionaries according to values of ONE key type?

Tags: python

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```py
[{'title': 'Shrek the Musical',   'year': 2013,   'genres': ['Comedy', 'Family', 'Fantasy'],   'duration': 130,   'directors': ['Michael John Warren'],   'actors': ["Brian d'Arcy James", 'Sutton Foster', 'Christopher Sieber'],   'rating': 7.0},
 {'title': 'Shrek Retold',   'year': 2018,   'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'],   'duration': 90,   'directors': ['Grant Duffrin'],   'actors': ['Harry Antonucci', 'Russell Bailey'],   'rating': 7.5},  
 {'title': 'Shrek 2',   'year': 2004,   'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'],   'duration': 93,   'directors': ['Andrew Adamson', 'Kelly Asbury'],   'actors': ['Mike Myers', 'Eddie Murphy'],   'rating': 7.2},  
 {'title': 'Shrek the Third',   'year': 2007,   'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'],   'duration': 93,   'directors': ['Chris Miller', 'Raman Hui'],   'actors': ['Mike Myers', 'Eddie Murphy', 'Cameron Diaz', 'Antonio Banderas'],   'rating': 6.1}, 
 {'title': 'Shrek Forever After',   'year': 2010,   'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'],   'duration': 93,   'directors': ['Mike Mitchell'],   'actors': ['Mike Myers', 'Eddie Murphy', 'Cameron Diaz', 'Antonio Banderas'],   'rating': 6.3}, 
 {'title': 'Shrek',   'year': 2001,   'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'],   'duration': 90,   'directors': ['Andrew Adamson', 'Vicky Jenson'],   'actors': ['Mike Myers', 'Eddie Murphy'],   'rating': 7.8}]
```

I want to produce a list of movies sorted in increasing order of their year of release. That is, the sorting should just depend on one value, ignoring all other keys.

I tried using the `sorted` function, but I don't know how to specify that the dictionaries should be sorted based on a single value.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `key` parameter to `sorted()` to tell it which key to sort on:

```py
result = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['year'])
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[{'title': 'Shrek', 'year': 2001, 'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'], 'duration': 90, 'directors': ['Andrew Adamson', 'Vicky Jenson'], 'actors': ['Mike Myers', 'Eddie Murphy'], 'rating': 7.8},
 {'title': 'Shrek 2', 'year': 2004, 'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'], 'duration': 93, 'directors': ['Andrew Adamson', 'Kelly Asbury'], 'actors': ['Mike Myers', 'Eddie Murphy'], 'rating': 7.2},
 {'title': 'Shrek the Third', 'year': 2007, 'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'], 'duration': 93, 'directors': ['Chris Miller', 'Raman Hui'], 'actors': ['Mike Myers', 'Eddie Murphy', 'Cameron Diaz', 'Antonio Banderas'], 'rating': 6.1},
 {'title': 'Shrek Forever After', 'year': 2010, 'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'], 'duration': 93, 'directors': ['Mike Mitchell'], 'actors': ['Mike Myers', 'Eddie Murphy', 'Cameron Diaz', 'Antonio Banderas'], 'rating': 6.3},
 {'title': 'Shrek the Musical', 'year': 2013, 'genres': ['Comedy', 'Family', 'Fantasy'], 'duration': 130, 'directors': ['Michael John Warren'], 'actors': ["Brian d'Arcy James", 'Sutton Foster', 'Christopher Sieber'], 'rating': 7.0},
 {'title': 'Shrek Retold', 'year': 2018, 'genres': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'], 'duration': 90, 'directors': ['Grant Duffrin'], 'actors': ['Harry Antonucci', 'Russell Bailey'], 'rating': 7.5}]
```